# Generate 100% CPU load in windows Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows

In Vb.NET i need to generate a lot of CPU usage. I have 4 threads that i can run the code through. I tried `Do : Loop` but the usage is not all ways 100% It goes from 80% to 95%

Comment: You should show your code in the question.

Comment: Try setting the threads .ThreadPriority property to Highest.  Caution - if this works you may have to manually power off your computer to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a console application, this will consume available ressources:

```
Sub Main()
    While True
        Process.Start(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
    End While
End Sub
```

**It will most likely crash your computer if you run it!!!**

It's called a fork bomb. Don't run it.

In more serious terms, give your CPU something to do in the loop, for example:

```
Parallel.For(1, 5, Sub(i)
                       While True
                           Dim a As Long = 100
                           Dim b As Long = 200
                           Dim c = Math.Sin(a ^ b)
                           Dim d = c
                       End While
                   End Sub)
```

Comment: Thanks! It is saying that it only uses up 90%-100% of the cpu but other things might be taking up the cycles. It lags a lot more than what i had before! +1

Comment: The sine and Pow is only an example. You can scale the work the CPU does up as much as you want with more expensive calculations of course. Or instead of the Parallel.For you can start a number of Tasks manually, maybe even more than the number of cores.